# Php loop through mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a page that is a confirm page for a form that was filled out. I have checked my sql statement and it works fine. The problem I'm having is getting the php loop to output the results without dumping the rest of the query.

So my code goes something like this:

```
$mysql-statement......
$total_rows... etc.

  $i = $total_rows;
    if($i > 1) { 
    echo "i = ". $i. "<br />";

    for($x=1; $x< ($i+1); $x++){
    echo "This is from the for loop Office location is " .$row_rs_myquery['Office_Name'] ."<br />"; 
        mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_myquery);
    }
      }?>
```

Now some of the above is for testing purposes and some of it I want, mainly I just want it to output the multiple Office Names that this person is associated with. Basically I am getting just the first office name and it isn't sorting through to the next office location associated with this person. It just repeats the same office location, the correct number of times I might add.

I have also tried a do while loop and that breaks the rest of the page for some reason. I am only looping through this one part but the rest of the page displays the persons contact information any anything else associated with them in the database. Just for sanity sake this is the do while statement I used. I have it running on a different page and this set up works on there so not sure why it wouldn't work on this page.

```
    do{
       echo "This is from the do while loop Office location is " .$row_rs_myquery['Office_Name'] ."<br />"; 
    }while($row_rs_myquery = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_myquery));
```

The current person I'm working on has 3 office locations under their name. So it should output 3 lines of code like such:

```
    This is from the for loop Office location is St. Paul

    This is from the for loop Office location is New York

    This is from the for loop Office location is Los Angeles
```

but what I'm getting is if I run the for loop

```
    This is from the for loop Office location is St. Paul

    This is from the for loop Office location is St. Paul

    This is from the for loop Office location is St. Paul
```

but what I'm getting is if I run the do while loop

```
    This is from the for loop Office location is St. Paul
```

and if I place this anywhere before the rest of the requests I get blank areas in my confirm page.

any ideas on why it would be doing this would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see your query (and database structure, if possible)?

Comment: Hint: If you wrap a `var_dump` around your fetch, i'm willing to bet you'll see either two `false`s, or two arrays.  For reference, though, if you weren't still using ext/mysql like the cavemen did, you'd be able to say `foreach ($rs_myQuery as $row) { /* print stuff */ }`.

Comment: actually when I did a var_dump on the array it shows stuff in there it just isn't go to the next result in the array as far as I can tell. I have each office with an office id and when I tell it to output that it is only showing the first one.

Comment: I didn't say var_dump the array.   I said var_dump the result from the fetch.  :)  Since you never modify `$row_rs_myquery` again, of course it's going to keep showing the same result.

Comment: if I do $row_rs_myquery = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_myquery) it should go to the next row in the query. I know this because it works perfectly fine on my other pages.

Answer (score 1):

For the do{}while loop, the condition is set only after the first iteration. You want just a while loop, which sets the variable before it runs.

```
while($row_rs_myquery = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_myquery)){
    echo "This is from the do while loop Office location is " .$row_rs_myquery['Office_Name'] ."<br />";
}
```

If you want to use the if loop (though the while loop works much better, IMO, especially since you aren't using X), you want to fetch the array before you try to use the variable:

```
for($x=1; $x<=$total_rows; $x++){
    $row_rs_myquery = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_myquery);
    echo "This is from the for loop Office location is " .$row_rs_myquery['Office_Name'] ."<br />"; 

}
```

Comment: Also `mysql_fetch_assoc` is deprecated, should use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` if possible.

Comment: @Skrivener: Of course, you mean "use `mysqli_connect`" and all that too.  :)  mysql_* and mysqli_* look and work alike if you use the procedural interface, but aren't compatible.

Comment: Yes, as you say @cHao, I was just being lazy :)

Comment: Yea when I put in the mysqli_fetch_assoc  stuff I get a bunch of errors. I know it might be deprecated but it is working at the moment aside from the not looping correct part. So I'm working on one broken bit at a time.

Comment: @aynber I actually do want the do while because every person should have at least 1 office associated with them. So it needs to run at least once then check to see if there are any other offices associated with this person and display the additional office names.

Comment: No, you want just a while, or else it won't assign the variable until after the first iteration. It will continue running until mysql_fetch_assoc returns false.

Comment: If I use the while loop I get nothing at all. So as far as I can tell the other rows hold nothing but they are clearly showing when I run my sql statement on my phpMyAdmin. So why would they show nothing when I put it in a page?

Comment: Unless you're assigning $row_rs_myquery or using mysql_fetch_assoc before you go into the loop, you should receive at least one line.

Comment: Ok let me explain I have a confirm page and it worked before I wanted to add this new office location list to the page. If I add it anywhere on the page with a do while or while loop it breaks the rest of the page leaving blank spaces. If I use the while loop it echos out nothing. I looked this up on the php.net and copied it from there and it gives no result.

Comment: Can you add in your full code from your mysql query to the end of your loop? There must be something we're not seeing in there.